# How to calculate AIC and BIC?

Tags: regression, python, aic, statsmodels, bic

I should find formula of BIC and AIC which is used in statsmodels.

I have array with values:

```
x = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]
y = [[0], [49], [101], [149], [201]]
```

And statsmodels model:

```
a = OLS(y, x).fit()
ols_cu.aic
```

> 16.54686499718649

I know that formula of statsmodels is

> -2. * llf + 2. * df_modelwc

Where

> df_modelwcis is 2 (in my array)
> llf should be np.log(MSE)

```
df_modelwcis = 2
SSE = np.dot(residual.T, residual)[0][0]
MSE = SSE/(len(x)-2)
aic = -2*np.log(MSE) + 2 * df_modelwcis
aic
```

> 3.635356886412113

What is the formula, where I did a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From wiki :
$AIC = 2k - 2\ln(L)$ where $L$ is maximum of the likelihood function and $k$ is the number of parameters estimated.

```
x = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]
y = [[0], [49], [101], [149], [201]]

res = sm.OLS(y, x).fit()

# Façon 1
res.aic # gives 16.5468

# Façon 2 
llf = res.llf # log-like value
k = 2
aic = -2*llf + 2 * k # gives 16.5468
```

@EDIT
The **loglike()** function is defined here [link](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py).

Without scale and offset (your case) :

```
nobs = 5
nobs2 = nobs / 2.0
nobs = float(nobs)
resid = res.resid

ssr = np.sum(resid ** 2)
llf = -nobs2 * np.log(2 * np.pi) - nobs2 * np.log(ssr / nobs) - nobs2 # gives -6.2734
```

You can calculate **BIC** easily: $BIC = \ln(n)k - 2\ln(L)$ following the same logic.

Comment: What is res.llf. Can you show calculation of res.llf?

Comment: [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/510040/statsmodels-ols-r2-calculation)
Can you check this question also?