# Statsmodels OLS R^2 calculation

Tags: python, least-squares, r-squared, statsmodels

I understand, that OLS of statsmodels sometimes uses centered and uncentered model for the calculation of R^2. Other calculations like tvalues, params, etc use only uncentered model. I want to understand when it uses centered and uncentered model
[image]

Comment: What is an un/centered model?

Comment: centered model is model with interecept(constant), uncentered without

Answer (score 1):

I uderstand how it works. If there is a constant value in the array, so formula of centered model will be used.
For example centered formula will be used when we have array in x axes like:

> [ [5, 1], [3, 1], [4, 1] ]

As wee see here, there is constant 1 in second column.
So Formula is

```
RSS = np.dot(np.transpose(residual), residual)
Reg = y - np.mean(y)
TSS = np.dot(np.transpose(Reg), Reg)
inv_tss = np.linalg.inv(TSS)
r2 = 1 - np.dot(RSS, inv_tss)
```

In the other situation it will be like

```
TSS = np.dot(np.transpose(y), y)
inv_tss = np.linalg.inv(TSS)
r2 = 1 - np.dot(RSS, inv_tss)
```

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/26205/35989

Comment: It will also use centered when the constant value is in the the matrix as a linear combination. For instance `[ [5, 6], [3, 4], [4, 5] ]`